# Fastest way to (auto)filter multiple criterias in Excel and delete non-matching rows?

Tags: excel, for-loop, filter, autofilter, vba

I have the following code that I am using as a workaround instead of filtering the data as I have multiple criterias. I read somewhere that it is only possible to filter 2 criterias at a time?
The thing is that I have 5 - `AB, DZ, RE, Z3, ZP` - everything else should be deleted. So I am using the code below, which works fine, but having to deal with +30000 rows everytime I run the macro, it is extremely slow.
Is there anyway you can do this faster? I was thinking of just filtering each criteria at a time (creating 5 of the first of the below codes). But if there is anyway to do it faster, I would appreciate some help.

**THE CODE I USE THAT IS SLOW:**

```
' Step 13 - Filter and Delete All Except
'           AB, DZ, RE, Z3, ZP in Column 6 - Type
Sub FilterDeleteType()
Dim rTable As Range, r As Range
Dim rDelete As Range
Set rDelete = Nothing
Dim v As Variant

Worksheets("Overdue Items").Activate

For Each r In Columns(6).Cells
    v = r.Value
    If v <> "Type" And v <> "AB" And v <> "DZ" And v <> "RE" And v <> "Z3" And v <> "ZP" Then
        If rDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rDelete = r
        Else
            Set rDelete = Union(r, rDelete)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rDelete Is Nothing Then rDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the usual and include: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of the code and revert back at the end.

Comment: Thank you @Ralph however, I do not see any difference in the speed :-(

Comment: You might be interested in this answer ["VBA Performance - Delete one million rows in less than 1 min"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959315/excel-vba-performance-1-million-rows-delete-rows-containing-a-value-in-less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do exactly what my previous code was doing, just significantly faster. With the help from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275522
What the code is doing is that it `filter` the values that I want (using an `array`), and then it will delete the hidden rows, meaning the rows that has NOT been filtered.

```
Sub FilterType()
Dim LRow As Long
Dim delRange As Range
Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRows As Range

Const Opt1 As String = "AB"
Const Opt2 As String = "DZ"
Const Opt3 As String = "RE"
Const Opt4 As String = "Z3"
Const Opt5 As String = "ZP"

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
Sheets(1).Activate
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    LRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("F1:F" & LRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4, Opt5), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

    With Sheets(1)
        Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("F:F").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
        If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With

    For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(6).Cells
    If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = oRow
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
        End If
    End If
    Next

ErrHandler:
    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just look in hidden rows and check that column -

```
Sub test()

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastcol As Integer
lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'do your autofilter here

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Rows(i).Hidden = True Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).ClearContents
        Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, lastcol)).ClearContents
        If Cells(i, 6) <> "AB" Or "DZ" Or "RE" Or "Z3" Or "ZP" Then
            Cells(i, 6).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @raystafarian I apologize for my late reply, I have been on vacation. But it is not working. I would have to filter manually to get this to work, which I am not interested in. Secondly, I am getting a run-time error when running it.

Comment: You can put your filter in where the comment "do your autofilter" is - this should fix the error and you won't need to manually filter

Comment: Hi again, you answer was somewhat useful, but I ended going another way. I upvoted it for guiding me in the right direction tho :) thanks.